# Mazur's Weak Basis Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, schauder-basis

It is the [Exercise 1.1](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=FkjCulO5xg0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA25&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) in *Topics in Banach Space Theory* by Albiac and Kalton to prove Mazur's Weak Basis Theorem, which states that every weak basis in a Banach space $X$ is a Schauder basis, where weak basis is defined as follows:

> A sequence $(e_n)_n$ in a Banach space $X$ is called a weak basis for $X$ if for every $x\in X$ there is an unique sequence of scalars $(a_n)$ such that $x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_ke_k$ in the weak topology.

I tried to show, to no avail, that $\lVert\sum^n a_kx_k\rVert\rightarrow\lVert x\rVert$ so that it would immediately follow that $\sum^n a_ne_n\overset{\lVert\cdot\rVert}{\rightarrow}x$. I'd like suggestions on how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is not correct, see the comment by Nate Eldregde. I do not see how to repair it.

---

Define the closure of the linear hull of the $(x_k)$ in the strong topology by
$$
C = \operatorname{cl \ span}\{x_k, k\in\mathbb N\}.
$$
It is convex and closed. We have to show that $C=X$ under the condition of weak basis. Let $x\in X\setminus C$ be given. Then we can separate $x$ and $C$ by $f\in X^*$: There is $\epsilon>0$ such that
$$
f(x) + \epsilon \le f(y) \quad\forall y\in C.
$$
Since $C$ is a linear space, $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in C$. In particular, $f(x_k)=0$ for all $k$. By assumption, there is a sequence $(a_k)$ such that
$\sum_{k=1}^n a_kx_k$ converges weakly to $x$ for $n\to\infty$.
This implies
$$
f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(\sum_{k=1}^n a_kx_k)
=  \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum _{k=1}^n a_k f(x_k)=0,
$$
which is a contradiction to $f(x)+\epsilon<0$.

Comment: Does this really suffice?  Saying $C=X$ is weaker than saying that $\{x_k\}$ is a Schauder basis.  For instance, if $X = C([0,1])$ and $x_k = x^k$ are the monomials, then $C=X$ (Weierstrass approximation theorem) but the monomials are not a Schauder basis (not every continuous function has a power series).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wonder if the proof can be repaired by using $C=$ set of strong limits of form $\sum a_kx_k$.

Answer (score 3):

The authors suggest in the exercise that we try to imitate the proof of [Theorem 1.1.3](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=FkjCulO5xg0C&lpg=PP1&hl=es&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false). Let us follow this kind suggestion.
Let $(e_k)_{k=1}^{\infty }$ be a weak basis. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define the linear maps
$e_n^{\#}\colon X\to \mathbb{K}$ by $e_n^{\#}(x)=a_n$ whenever
$x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k e_k$ in the weak topology. Note that $e_n^{\#}(e_m)=\delta _{nm}$,
where $\delta _{nm}$ denotes the usual Kronecker delta, so if we show
that:

1. $e_n^{\#}$ are bounded
2. $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e_n^\#(x) e_n $ in the usual norm.

Then, it will follow that
$(e_k)_{k=1}^{\infty }$ is a Schauder basis.

**Let us prove 1:**

For this purpose, it clearly suffices to show that the natural projections
$$
S_n\bigg( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_ke_k \bigg) =\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_ke_k
$$
are bounded for all $n\ge 1$. By hypothesis $S_nx\xrightarrow{w}x$ for
all $x \in X$, so the sequence $(S_nx)_{n=1}^{\infty }$ is norm
bounded, and it makes sense to define $|||x|||=\sup_{n\ge 1}
\|S_nx\|$. It is direct to check that $|||{\cdot }|||$ is a norm.
Also, since $x^{*}(S_nx)\to x^{*}(x)$ for all $x^{*} \in X^{*}$, we
have
$$
|x^{*}(x)|\leq \sup_{n\ge 1}|x^{*}(S_nx)|
$$
which implies
$$
\|x\|=\sup_{\|x^{*}\|\le 1}|x^{*}(x)|\le \sup_{\|x^{*}\|\le
1}\sup_{n\ge 1} |x^{*}(S_nx)|=|||x|||.
$$
We have thus shown that $\|{\cdot }\|\le |||{\cdot }|||$.

Our next goal is to prove that the space $(X,|||{\cdot }|||)$ is
complete. To do this, let $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty }$ be a Cauchy sequence
in $|||{\cdot }|||$. By the inequality shown above, $(x_n)$ is Cauchy
in $\|{\cdot }\|$, and so it converges to some $x \in X$. We will show
that $(x_n)$ also converges to $x$ in $|||{\cdot }|||$. Fixed any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $\|S_kx_n-S_kx_m\|\le |||x_n-x_m|||$, so the
sequence $(S_kx_n)$ converges to a certain $y_k \in X$ in the original
norm $\|{\cdot}\|$. Also, by its very definition, $S_kx_n \in
\text{span}\{e_1,\ldots ,e_k\}$, and since finite-dimensional
subspaces are closed, $y_k \in \text{span}\{e_1,\ldots ,e_k\}$.
Another important property of finite-dimensional spaces is that any
linear operator is continuous, so we must have
$$e_j^{\#}(x_n)=e_j^{\#}(S_kx_n)\to e_j^{\#}(y_k)\quad\text{for }1\le j\le k.$$

Now we claim that $y_k\xrightarrow{w} x$. To show this, fix $x^{*}\in
X^{*}$ and $\varepsilon >0$. Choose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$|||x_n-x_m|||<\varepsilon$ for every $m\ge n$ (this is possible
because $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $|||{\cdot}|||$), and choose $k_0\in
\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x^{*}(x_n)-x^{*}(S_kx_n)|<\varepsilon$ for all
$k\ge k_0$ (this is possible because $S_kx_n\xrightarrow{w}x_n$). Then for $k\ge k_0$:
\begin{align}
    |x^{*}(y_k)-x^{*}(x)|&\le \lim_{m\to \infty
    }|x^{*}(S_kx_m)-x^{*}(S_kx_n)|\\&+|x^{*}(S_kx_n)-x^{*}(x_n)|+\lim_{m\to
    \infty } |x^{*}(x_n)-x^{*}(x_m)|\\
    &\le \|x^{*}\|\lim_{m\to \infty } |||x_m-x_n|||+ \varepsilon
    +\|x^{*}\|\lim_{m\to \infty }|||x_m-x_n|||\\
    &\le (2\|x^{*}\|+1)\varepsilon .
\end{align}
So $x^{*}(y_k)\to x^{*}(x)$ for all $x^{*} \in X^{*}$. In other words,
$$
    y_k=\sum_{j=1}^{k} e_j^{\#}(y_k)e_j\xrightarrow{w} x,
$$
and since the expansion of $x$ in the weak basis $(e_j)$ is unique, it
follows that $y_k=S_kx$. With this we can finally show that
\begin{align}
    |||x_n-x|||&=\sup_{k\ge 1} \|S_kx_n-S_kx\|\\
               &=\sup_{k\ge 1} \|S_k x_n-y_k\|\\
               &=\sup_{k\ge 1}\lim_{m\to \infty } \|S_kx_n-S_kx_m\|\\
               &\le \limsup_{m\to \infty }
               |||x_n-x_m|||\xrightarrow[n\to \infty ]{}0,
\end{align}
and therefore $(X,|||{\cdot }|||)$ is complete.

We are almost done. We have already shown that the identity map $id_X\colon
(X,\|{\cdot}\|)\to (X,|||{\cdot }|||)$ is continuous (this is
precisely the inequality we proved at the beginning), and so it is an
isomorphism by the [Bounded Inverse Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem). Hence there exists a
constant $C>0$ such that $|||x|||\le C\|x\|$, that is, such that
$\|S_k\|\le C$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. And this finishes the proof.

**Let us prove 2:**

We first notice $X=\overline{span\{e_n\:|\: n \in \mathbb{N}\}}$. Indeed, if $x\in X\setminus \overline{span\{e_n\:|\: n \in \mathbb{N}\}} $, by geometric Hahn Banach, there would exist $f$ that separates them strictly. Therefore we arrive at the following contradiction:

$$0\not=f(x)=f(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e_k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k f(e_k)=0$$

Because it is dense, we may find a sequence $x_n\rightarrow x$ such that $x_n \in span\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ (going to a subsequence if necessary and repeating terms if necessary).  Clearly:

$$\lVert S_n(x)-x\rVert = \lVert S_n(x)-S_n(x_n)+x_n-x\rVert \leq (\sup_n \lVert S_n \rVert+1)\lVert x-x_n \rVert\rightarrow 0$$

Indeed, $S_n(x)$ converges weakly to $x$, so it is norm bounded and by Banach Steinhaus, $\sup_n \lVert S_n\rVert<\infty$. Thus, $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k e_k$ in the usual norm.